# Complex Integration - Linearity

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Complex integration is defined as:
$$
\int f dy=\text{Re}(\int f dy)+i \cdot \text{Im}(\int f dy)=\int \text{Re}(f) dy+i \cdot \int \text{Im}(f) dy
$$
Why is
$$
\mid \int f dy \mid\leq \int \mid f\mid dy
$$
with $\mid f(x)\mid = \sqrt{\text{Re}^2(f(x))+\text{Im}^2(f(x))}$?

Comment: Here you have to use that $\left|\int f dy \right | = c\int f dy$ where $|c| = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\int f(x)dx=re^{i\theta}$ with $r \geq 0$ and $\theta $ real. Then $\int \Re (e^{-i\theta} f(x) )dx \leq \int|e^{-i\theta} f(x)| dx=\int |f(x)| dx$. Left side equals $\Re (e^{-i\theta}\int f(x)dx)=r= |\int f(x)dx|$.

Alternative proof: let $u$ and $v$ be the real and imaginary parts of $f$ respectively. Let $a, b  \in \mathbb R$. Then $au+bv \leq \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}\sqrt {u^{2}+v^{2}}$. Integrating this we get $a\int u+b\int v \leq \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}} \int |f|$ since $\sqrt {u^{2}+v^{2}}=|f|$. Now put $a=\int u$ and $b =\int v$. You will see easily that this leads to the desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any other way to show this?

Comment: I have added another proof.

Comment: thank you very much